# error: (linebreak): invalid node with type whatsit and subtype 19 found in discretionary

Tags: fonts, hyperref, luatex

When trying to build the following document with LuaLaTeX, it fails on my computer with the error in the title:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}
See also \href{https://en.wiktionary.org/}{Wiktio}.
\end{document}
```

Weirdly, it works if I change the link text to just `Wikti`, remove the link or use a different font.

I was **unable** to reproduce it on Overleaf so perhaps it has something to do with fonts installed on my computer? I tried clearing `~/.texlive2021/` but it did not help.

Any idea what does the message mean or how to interpret it?

Full log:

```
$ lualatex  pisma.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (Web2C 2021/NixOS.org) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./pisma.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
 L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class

(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/size10.clo
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-01.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex)))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty))
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf)) (./pisma.aux)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/nix/store/xygf45hbpwbrwhixhrpi4kdp6dyikd5g-texlive-combined-2021/share/texmf/
tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty)) (./pisma.out) (./pisma.out)
! error:  (linebreak): invalid node with type whatsit and subtype 19 found in d
iscretionary
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Please report this at [the luaotfload issue tracker](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Done: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/191

Answer (score 1):

This is a luaotfload bug which will be fixed with the next luaotfload update, but until then you can work around it by using the Node shaper instead of HarfBuzz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[Renderer=Node]{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}
See also \href{https://en.wiktionary.org/}{Wiktio}.
\end{document}
```

[image]